# Why is cin incorrectly reading words that start with certain characters

Tags: c++

I'm working through Accelerated C++, and I'm compiling and testing the grading program from chapter 4. For some reason, `cin` is not able to properly read names that start with certain characters. For example:

```
$ echo "zach 1 1 1 fred 2 2 2 albert 3 3 3 james 4 4 4 adam 5 5 5" | ./main 
james 4
lbert 3
m     5
red   2
zach  1
```

You can see that names starting with an A or an F will get misread, and at least one character will be cut off from the front.

After I saw this bug in my code, I copied from someone who's posted [solutions to every single problem](http://mathalope.co.uk/2014/07/23/accelerated-c-solution-to-exercise-4-0/) online, and I'm still seeing the bug. Printing to the console shows that the names are being read in like that. I'm really baffled by this, and cannot think of any explanation as to why this is happening.

Also, this is **exclusive** to Mac. I compiled and ran this on my Windows machine and it returned the correct output. Then I tried it on my other Mac and got the incorrect output again.

Here's an MRE version of the program in question that follows the patterns given in the book and shows similar behavior:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::istream;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

double sum_vec(vector<double> &vec)
{
    double total = 0;
    for (vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        total += vec[i];
    }
    return total;
}

istream &read_nums(istream &in, vector<double> &vec)
{
    if (in)
    {
        vec.clear();

        double x;
        while (in >> x)
            vec.push_back(x);

        in.clear();
    }
    return in;
}

istream &read(istream &in)
{
    string s;
    in >> s;

    vector<double> vec;

    read_nums(in, vec);

    double total = sum_vec(vec);

    cout << s << " " << total << endl;

    return in;
}

int main()
{
    while (read(cin))
    {
    }
}
```

After compiling as `test` you can see the following:

```bash
$ echo "albert 1 bruce 2 chris 3 dan 4 edward 5 fanny 6" | ./test
albert 1
ruce 2
hris 3
4 0
ward 5
y 6
 0
```

Compiled by running

```bash
g++ -o test test.cpp
```

Running `g++ --version` returns:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: hi, perhaps step through the code or paste here

Comment: Indeed. Please show us the code.

Comment: For sure, I included the link to the code I used since I thought that would be cleaner, but I can put the code in the post itself

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You'll find many other questions here, with a [mre], in plain text. Please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: Made the requested edits - thank you everyone for helping!

Comment: I'm afraid you missed minimal by a couple city blocks. The real reason we like [mre]s (MREs) is the process of making one almost always exposes the bug and eliminates the need for the question. make the MRE early in the debugging process and you're usually done early.

Comment: Gotcha, I can probably whip up an MRE in a few minutes

Comment: @user4581301 I replaced the code with an MRE that operates in a similar manner to the code given in the book, and shows similar results.

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately it looks like it works: https://godbolt.org/z/fferhvT73 Oh. No it doesn't. Dropped fanny.

Comment: Found her. Wasn't terminating the input correctly in my test example. Can't reproduce the Swiss cheese-ed  output you were getting.

Comment: Yea I just tried to run it on my Windows machine and got the correct output. So it's exclusive to mac then?

Comment: Looks like it's a libc++ thing https://godbolt.org/z/3Ys9GGv8f. Looks like when reading the doubles it's consuming hex characters

Comment: In general there's no guarantee that a failed read hasn't consumed some characters, if you want that behaviour you'd have to read in a string then attempt to convert the string

Comment: Regardless of whether it's a library bug or not, reading numbers like that is terrible style. Read a line, then parse a line. In the original problem, there is one student record per line.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yea I just input using `echo` to minimize copying/pasting while testing, since my shell would just remember the whole input + command. I tested with newlines too and it didn't make a difference

Comment: I'm assuming that using `getline` is a more modern input pattern, right? maybe one that wasn't around in 2000, when the book was last updated?

Comment: I would assume that the authods just didn't get around to introducing it. They cover a smallish subset of C++ after all. And they didn't know about the libc++ bug back then...